# When are two functions related by a coordinate change?

Tags: functional-analysis, functions, coordinate-systems

Consider two $\underline{\text{injective}}$ functions $X: R^m \to R^n$ and $Y: R^m \to R^n$ with $m<n$. How do I decide if there exists a (smooth, invertible) coordinate transformation $\sigma: R^m\to R^m$ such that $X=Y\circ \sigma$?

Comment: For a start, the images of $X$ and $Y$ have to be the same as subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Beyond that things seem difficult. Do you have a specific case in mind?

Comment: Interesting question, beginning with $m=n=1$...

Comment: @JeanMarie I think in $m=n=1$, the images have to agree and the sequence of the signs of the first derivative must agree (because the change of coordinates has positive derivative).

Comment: I agree. I don't see in which way this characterization can be extended to the next case $m=2,n=1$... beyond the fact the images have to be identical.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Actually the case I had in mind was injective functions.